# Insert and update trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table with columns `uploaddate` and `systemuser` and a trigger to add user and date for new record

```
USE [ITPrinter]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg01]
ON [dbo].[Printers]
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Printers
    SET UploadDate = GETDATE(), SystemUser = SUSER_SNAME()
    WHERE id IN (SELECT ID FROM inserted)
END
```

It works fine.

Now I create 2 new columns, `changedate` and `changeuser` in the same table.
My goal to update record which alter by user and date alter. BUT NOT CHANGE info in columns `UploadDate` and `SystemUser`.

This is my second trigger

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg02]
ON [dbo].[Printers]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE p
    SET p.ChangeDate = GETDATE(), p.ChangeUser = SUSER_SNAME()
    FROM Printers p
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON p.id = i.id
```

But this did not work, I get this error

> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry, it's SQL

Comment: **SQL** is just the **Structured Query Language** - a **language** used by many RDBMS for their work. That doesn't tell us anything, really. You need to post the name of a **concrete database PRODUCT** - not just "SQL" .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on The code and the error message we are dealing with Microsoft SQL Server.

looks like your database is configured for [recursive triggers.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#recursive-triggers)

To disable directly recursive triggers (meaning, an update trigger fired by an update made in on the table by the same update trigger), you can disable recursive triggers by using `alter database`:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDataBase SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF;
GO
```

You can also set trigger nesting level to 0 to disable both direct and indirect trigger recursion, but I would recommend using this step with caution - especially if you use triggers to enforce business rules.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'nested triggers', 0 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Comment: use this code on second trigger ? Correct me if I'm wrong or no way to set second trigger to get update?

Comment: No, do not use this code inside the trigger. This is a database configuration code, you only need to run this once (or better yet, ask your DBA to set it for you, if you have a DBA working with you)

Comment: So I guess use only one trigger for insert or update. If yes, any way I can achieve my goal?

Comment: No, separate triggers for insert and update are valid, as long as they do different things (and in this case, the do). The problem is that your update trigger is executing an update on the same table, and that updates fires the update trigger again and again....